# Spacing within Chemical equations

Tags: spacing, equations, chemistry

My Chemistry equations come out looking a bit awkward when it comes to writing compounds, which require multiple letters. Here's an example, note the space between H and N, or B and F:
[image]

I couldn't find any package to use that could help with this, nor any previously answered questions about this kind of thing.

If it is useful, here's the code:

```
\begin{equation}

\huge BF_3 + NH_3 \rightleftharpoons BF_3 NH_3

\end{equation}
```

What could I do to get rid of that sort of spacing?

Comment: You must get errors from that you can not have blank lines or font size commands such as `\huge` in an `equation`  there are packages for setting chemisry such as mhchem

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Do search this site for postings with the `chemistry` tag.

Comment: see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201835/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\huge` didn't seem to give me an error, and I would get the same problem whether or not I have a font size command. However, I looked at the example you sent, and it seemed that using `\ce` helped fix my issue, thanks!

Comment: You get a warning not an error (the blank line is an error) `huge` generates `LaTeX Font Warning: Command \huge invalid in math mode on input line 6`  that is a warning you should not ignore though,  the command does not work in math.

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidCarlisle has already noted in a comment, loading the [mhchem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) package and using its `\ce` ("chemical equation") macro would constitute a good start.

`\ce` can be used in both text and math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem
\begin{document}

\begin{center} % text mode
\huge
\ce{BF3 + NH3 \rightleftharpoons BF3NH3}
\end{center}

\[  % math mode
\ce{BF3 + NH3 \rightleftharpoons BF3NH3}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can write `<=>` instead of `\rightleftharpoons` in both `mhchem` and `chemformula`

Comment: @cgnieder - Thanks for this. It's definitely easier (for me at least) to remember `<=>`.